# How to make odd all elements of a list in python?

Tags: python

I have an array of multiple even and odd numbers, how can i make this array to an arrary of odd elements, for example:
odd elements ignored but even elements plus 1;

```
Input_array = [3,67,2,34,55,73,96,21,13,15,16]
Output_array = [3,67,3,35,55,73,97,21,13,15,17]
```

this is my code :

```
Output_array = [(x+1) for x in Input_array if x%2 == 0]
```

but this `Output_array` contains (even elements + 1) not all elements, only `[3, 35, 97, 17]`

Comment: You could just pull each value out of the array in a for loop, check if it's even or odd, do stuff and then add to output array.

Comment: `[x +1 if x % 2 == 0 else x for x in Input_array]`

Comment: BTW, please don't call a [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list) an [`array`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html#array.array). Those two are different things.

Comment: `[x + 1 - x % 2 for x in Input_array]`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just set their 1-bit:

```
[x | 1 for x in a]
```

Demo:

```
>>> a = [3,67,2,34,55,73,96,21,13,15,16]
>>> [x | 1 for x in a]
[3, 67, 3, 35, 55, 73, 97, 21, 13, 15, 17]
```

Comment: Yep, this is much better than my solution. Very nice. +1

Answer (score 6):

As you've correctly observed, you can convert a list of even and odd elements to only odd elements by adding `1` to the even elements. You also know this can be done with a list comprehension. Your code is close, but not quite right. Right now, all you're doing is *filtering out any odd numbers* from your new list. If the current element *is not* even, you need to *add it* to the new list:

```
[x + 1 if x % 2 == 0 else x for x in Input_array]
```

Here is what the above list comprehension produces:

```
>>> Input_array = [3,67,2,34,55,73,96,21,13,15,16]
>>> [x + 1 if x % 2 == 0 else x for x in Input_array]
[3, 67, 3, 35, 55, 73, 97, 21, 13, 15, 17]
>>>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use:

```
[x+(not x % 2) for x in Input_array]
```

This works as follows, with the condition `not x % 2`, we check if the number is even (`True` if is even, `False` otherwise). Since `True` is as an integer `1`, and `False` as an integer is `0`, we thus add `1` to the value, given the number is even.

This gives us:

```
>>> [x+(not x % 2) for x in Input_array]
[3, 67, 3, 35, 55, 73, 97, 21, 13, 15, 17]
```

Or we can use bitwise operations:

```
[x-(x&1)+1 for x in Input_array]
```

The result is again:

```
>>> [x-(x&1)+1 for x in Input_array]
[3, 67, 3, 35, 55, 73, 97, 21, 13, 15, 17]
```

Comment: Points for creativity :-) +1

Comment: For the bitwise solution @StefanPochmann shows it more simply with `x | 1` instead of `x-(x&1)+1`.  Unfortunately, the clarity of the bitwise solution is limited to those who twiddle bits.  Using the integer nature of booleans I think also makes some readers pause.  So while both of your answers are smart, but I prefer the straightforwardness of `x + 1 if x % 2 == 0 else x` while simultaneously disliking its verbosity.   I'm somewhat fond of `x + 1 - x%2`, but it also lacks clarity so I don't have a better answer.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: I'm not a huge fan of bithacks either, if you do not really work with bits. But it is more *spielerei* :).

Answer (score 1):

The reason your statement `Output_array = [(x+1) for x in Input_array if x%2 == 0]` does not work is: you are filtering the list and only use elements that are even - to those you add 1.

```
[x+1 if x%2 == 0 else x for x in Input_array]
```

processes all elements of Input_array and adds 1 to the even ones, leaves the odd ones as is.

<strike>`[x+1 if x%2 == 0 for x in Input_array`</strike>

processes all elements of Input_array and adds 1 to the even ones, ignoreing all odd ones.

```
[x+1 for x in Input_array if x%2 == 0]
```

processes only even elements of Input_array and adds 1 to the even ones.

---

What would work as well is:

```
[x+ (x-1)% 2 for x in Input_array]
```

If it is an even number the `(x-1) % 2` will produce `1` and make it odd, if it is already odd `(x-1) % 2` will produce `0` an leave it as is.

Comment: The second attempt is invalid syntax.